# Xml layout file has too many views. How can I reduce them?

Tags: xml, android-layout

My xml layout file has about 30 repeating LinearLayouts like the ones in the code snippet. Each LinearLayout contains two TextViews and one ImageView. The problem is that in android studio i get a message saying I have more than 80 views, and that the maximum number of views you can have is 80.
So my question is: How can I reduce the number of views I use?

`

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/LL1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TV1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="book"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="책"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_gray_orange_ring"
                    android:src="@mipmap/audio_white_clear"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                />
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LL2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/white">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TV2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="expensive"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="책"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_gray_orange_ring"
                android:src="@mipmap/audio_white_clear"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
            />
        </LinearLayout>`
```

Comment: for repeating Linear layouts you can use listview for particular part

Comment: Don't layout views based on `LinearLayout`, use `RelativeLayout` instead, it could reduce your nesting. Use `RecyclerView` for repetable views. And you should post code on stack overflow in text format, not image one. You have such option in editor

Comment: Sorry, first post. I did it on my phone where there was no option for including code.

Comment: Any advice on how to combine my xml drawable object with my mipmap.png image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My layout file has 20-30 repeating Linear layouts which contain two TextViews and one ImageView.

This is the recipe for using `RecyclerView`

You should definitely take a look at [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) from the android developers' tutorials

A tip to get you started, you repeating `LinearLayout` could be a row in your `RecyclerView`

This will get you started ;)

Comment: Thanks. I guess i need to look into that a bit more. Any ideas on how i can combine my xml drawable with my mipmap.png image to make one image? I guess this same thing will make my life more difficult when i do the recyclerview

Comment: @Ntwofive can you explain better what you mean by " combine my xml drawable with my mipmap.png image to make one image?"

Comment: I have an xml defined oval shape which i use as the background for my IageView which I then add  a .png image from mipmap to as the android:src attr

Comment: android:background="@drawable/circle_gray_orange_ring"
android:src="@mipmap/audio_white_clear"

Comment: @Ntwofive alright so you have the background and the src drawable, so it seems that you are on the good path , is it not working?

Comment: @Ntwofive Please post a new question with this so I can give you the code (I already made it).  

By the way I think part of the reason somebody voted down this question is that you made it a quite confusing post by making two very different questions in a single post (in my opinion) 
After posting the question post the link here and I will answer it with the code

Comment: I was going to post a new question but wasnt allowed to yet as I dont have enough points. I will try and post it tomorrow. Thanks

Comment: @Ntwofive alright try again tomorrow and post the link here or I will never find it xD

Afterwards I can help you edit and improve this question so you get more points

Comment: Thanks, but it would seem I have already been cut. No more posts allowed

Comment: @Ntwofive that is very strange... what's the error that you're getting?